# Docker container cannot be restarted because the python app service gets sucked and cannot be killed

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

My python app (using Tornado web framework) is running in an alpine linux container, and pretty often it gets into a weird state when it becomes unresponsive. (at this moment i have no clue what is causing this problem)
Once it gets into this state, I cannot even restart that container. The only way to recover from it will be to restart the docker service (note that this is a development environment so i have some access there).
When i remote connected to that container and tried to kill the problematic python service, i realize that no matter what kill command i use, that project doesn't get killed.
Any idea what is going on there?

```
bash-5.0# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.11.5
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.11"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
bash-5.0#


bash-5.0# python --version
Python 3.6.10
```

[image]

Comment: Your process seems to be in zombie state. This can happen if process up the call stack go stuck. How did you start the container? What is above the process in `pstree`?

Comment: The thing is that the process starts properly. And runs properly for a while. And then it gets into this state

Comment: You have not answered my questions.